# Using nmap to traceroute on a specific port

Tags: networking, port, traceroute, nmap

The short version of this is that from client A to server B, some connections are getting all the way there, and others are being dropped in transit. 
I know they're being dropped in transit because, when I do a tcpdump at the server, I see hits for the ports that work, but nothing for the ones that don't.

I tried the `nmap` command:

```
nmap -p <port> --traceroute <dst_ip>
```

which works perfectly when the connection is successful, but if the connection fails for whatever reason, it marks the port as filtered and then switches to icmp for the traceroute.

Is there something I can do to force the traceroute to stay in the port supplied even if the connection is unsuccessful? I need to be able to see how far the specific port(s) get before being dropped.

Example `nmap` commands and outputs here:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any parameter to control this behavior in the document of nmap.

If you want to find which hop drops the specific packet, you may try to use traceroute. The parameter `-P` is for protocol and `-p` is for port.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the Windows tracert is pretty basic and doesn't have half the options that the unix traceroute has which is why I was trying to use nmap since it SEEMED to have exactly what I wanted, but then I ran into this behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Nmap specifically chooses probes for traceroute from what it knows about the target, choosing probes that are most likely to make it all the way to the target. For this reason, its traceroute is not really useful for debugging dropped packets, but is excellent for quickly tracing the path *without* knowing what will reach the target.

I've just put in a [feature request for this](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/458) to be part of the Nping tool, which is developed by the Nmap Project and seems to be a good platform for such a capability. In the meantime, as @StevenLee mentions, there are existing traceroute tools that can specify which port to traceroute.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the -Pn switch

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your answer could benefit from more detail (See [answer]). Please edit it to explain how  your solution works/how it addresses the OPs question.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. nmap still switches to using icmp if tcp port is filtered.